# dynamically create sub arrays

Tags: javascript

I have below mentioned array. these array values are from Database:

If  the loop finds APP string, then it should add remaining field (including APP value ) to new array. How to do it.. Help plz

```
var applications=new Array("App", "sub", "child", "App1", "sub1", "sub0", "child1", "App2", "sub2", "child2");
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```
var applicationArrays = [];
for (var i = 0; i < applications.length; i++) {
    if (applications[i].search("App") != -1)
        applicationArrays[applicationArrays.length] = [applications[i]];
    else
        applicationArrays[applicationArrays.length - 1].push(applications[i]);
};
```

Your array would produce the following:

[image: chrome console log]

Comment: If the string starts with APP, then it creates a new array from there. It should automatically create 3 arrays with below result for above Array. Note array b have 4 values.

Array A having values ("App", "sub", "child")
Array b( "App1", "sub1", "sub0", "child1")
array c( "App2", "sub2", "child2")

Comment: So you want 3 individual arrays rather than an array of arrays?

Comment: _"It should automatically create 3 arrays"_ - And that's what jeff's code does (+1), putting each sub array as an element of `applicationArrays`. Presumably you need to add the individual arrays into some "master" array as per this answer because you don't know how many will be created. If you want something else please edit your question to show exactly what the desired output is.

Comment: My results should be exactly like JEFF's output. how to assign these array values OR print the arrays.

Comment: @Nash - I'm not sure what you mean. If my code produces the desired result, what additional assignments must you use? As for printing the result to the console, use `console.log(applicationArrays);`. If you're talking about printing the result on the page just loop through them to output what you want.

Comment: NOw, I am trying the same for sub. Below code not working.  
function hello()
{
 var applications=new Array("App", "sub", "child", "App1", "sub1", "sub0", "child1", "App2", "sub2", "child2");
var applicationArrays = [];
var subArrays = [];
for (var i = 0; i < applications.length; i++) {
if (applications[i].search("App") != -1)
{
        applicationArrays[applicationArrays.length] = [applications[i]];
        if(applications[i].search("sub") != -1)
{
subArrays[subArrays.length] = [applicationArrays[i]];
}
}
else
{applicationArrays[applicationArrays.length - 1].push(applications[i]);}
}; 
}

Comment: @Nash - Why did you add the `subArrays` variable? `applicationArrays` should contain the subarrays already. You can rename it if you want, but don't add another variable...

Comment: Jeff, The above array contains the tree node variables. All APP's contains the main nodes and sub nodes, SUB contains the second sub nodes and child contains the last nodes. So I am getting the sub nodes in another array.